# Can I extract a list with a button in infopath 2010?

Tags: 2010, infopath, excel

I'm working on sharepoint 2010. I want to know if it's possible to create a button which extract the list the infopath is based on in an excel sheet.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "the list the infopath is based on" means that you are talking about a SharePoint list form that you are customising with InfoPath.

In that case, the answer is: No, you cannot create a button in the form that extracts the whole list to Excel. Such functionality would require code that is not available in InfoPath list forms.

You can export the SharePoint list view to Excel using the ribbon button in the browser.

Comment: ok thank you for your quick reply. However, do you think it is possible to create a button like this in sharepoint designer? Thanks.

Comment: The button already exists. On the ribbon. You may need to step back and explain the bigger picture. Please don't do that in a comment. Edit your question and add more detail.